# Unstable Lower And Upper Voltage Charger Wall Adapter For Charging Battery

Tags: charger

i have 2 charger adapter and both of them i testing with usb meter tester

Charger A : Showing 4.92V-4.96V (the number keep moving ups and down between 4.92V-4.96V when high load)

Charger B : Showing 5.12V-5.19V (stable at 5.16V sometimes ups and down to 5.12V and 5.19V when high load).

which one are good or safest one to use for charging my smartphone and portable music player walkman (sony nw zx300)? both device required 5V for charging the batteries
and also i do want to know if im using not stable voltage especially lower voltage like charger A or upper voltage like charger B would it damaged batteries if i use it in long term?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The fluctuations <s>are called "ripple" and the amount that you described</s> look normal to me.

According to Battery Charging Specification v1.2 the allowed bus voltage tolerance is 5% in DCP mode (the mode that most wall chargers have). Both chargers' outputs are in that range. So there shouldn't be any problems.

Your concern should be the max output current of the charger and the charge current need of the device to be charged. In any ways, since most wall chargers provide at least 500mA, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Actual if they are steady enough to read on DMM it is called load regulation not ripple

Comment: currently i can use both charger for charging my devices and excatly like you say there is no problem , the chargers itself provide 2.1A for Charger A and 2.4A for charger B even though my devices especially sony zx300 only need 1A , the things bother me only from load regulation (unstable) voltage output but lower than it required  and stable voltage output but higher than it required . thanks for helping i think i will stay with charger A

Answer (score 0):

Battery chargers  are capable of excess power, but smart battery mobiles control/regulate charge current to limit to their battery needs.

As long as voltage is with 10% it is OK.

2% load regulation is Normal fluctuations from cable for a consumer quality product.  For example , Universal laptop chargers often use 2 extra wires for   remote voltage sense feedback from the plug to allow for thinner more flexible cables to the plug and maintain better load regulation. You may recall some adapters with 4 pins.

Comment: so as long as it doesn't below 4.5V and higher than 5.5V its consider safe to use right? thanks for sharing i think will stick with charger A